# How to partition a disk for installing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-vista

Currently I'm running Vista on my laptop but it's getting slower each day, so I decide to install an Ubuntu on my laptop, while for some reason I still need to keep the Vista.

Right now I have two disks under Vista: C:/ for the Vista system and installed software,

```
D:/ for my personal data, e.g, music, movie, photo.
```

I want to keep some of the personal data and delete something unnecessary to spare about 50GB space.

So my question is this: is there a way to 'cut' the free 50GB into a independent disk, say E:/, so I can install Ubuntu on it, while not affecting my Vista system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is a way... I'll guide you through the procedure... Here goes...

U can do all of the Hard Drive Re-sizing, Partitioning without loosing data using a Propitiatory Software for Windows with which you can literally control your NTFS/FAT Partitions. Its called EASEUS Partition Master v5.5 Pro. How to get it? You'll have to work out that. Its not that hard to find it.

Once u have the software, make your Hard drive look like something like what I've shown Below.

> [······300000 MB······] [··········1000000 MB··········] [····200000 MB·····]
>
> ```
>    Windows XP              Data             FREE Space
>       NTFS                 NTFS            (for Ubuntu)
> ```

[image: Partitions]

Once you have 20-25 GB, delete the partition i.e. your marking it as free space. Once done you can go ahead with Ubuntu installation in this way.

Boot from Live CD and start the Installation.
During Installation Select Specify Partitions Manually. To begin creating partitions, **select the free space and click on the *Add…* button**.
[image: Manual Partitioning]

- Click on the "Add" button. In the new window, type 2048 in the "New partition size in megabytes" field and select the "swap area" option from the "Use as:" list. Click the OK button (your swap area should be twice your ram size - Recommended). [image: SWAP]
- Now, click on the "Add" button. In the new window, select the "Primary" option, input a value between 8,000 and 20,000 in the "New partition size in megabytes" field and select / as the "Mount point." Click the OK button. [image: New partition]
- Click on the “Add” button again and from the new window and select the "Primary" option, type in whatever space you have left in your hard disk in the "New partition size in megabytes" field. And select /home as the "Mount point". Click the OK button. You are done with the hard part.

Click "Install Now" to proceed with the installation process.

Comment: Please let me know if u have been able to find the Software.. I could help u out, if u haven't :)

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu can manage the partitioning itself, it recognizes the windows and should prompt you with the   `install ubuntu alongside windows`.
selecting this option, ubuntu will create a new partition for you automatically without harming windows nor your data.

after you select that option, you will see a SLIDER. where you can move it, in order to increase the amount of drive you want ubuntu or windows to have. and you are done.

please note:

- you can access your windows files from ubuntu. but you can't access ubuntu files from windows. possible but not easy.
- make sure you delete all the unwanted files on windows, so you can have more space for ubuntu.
- you can do the partitioning manually also. to customize your /home partition or /boot or the swap partition. but if this is the first time you use ubuntu i reccomend the automatic one.
- you can still enlarge or make partitions smaller after the install with the live cd and gparted. so don't worry.

good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is perfectly possible to install Ubuntu next to Windows. You would have to cut free enough space for the installation, that's right and it could be wise to have this space free on one partition. The Installer on the Ubuntu-CD shows the Option to install Ubuntu alongside to Windows, so this is not really difficult. You also don't need 50 gB of free disk space, even 10 Gb would be completely sufficient and you can access the data stored on your Windows Partitions from Ubuntu, for accessing you Ubuntu data on your Windows Vista you need to install a [free 3rd party driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) and after that you will be able to see your Ubuntu partitions on Windows Vista.

Also note, that you don't have to make an E:\ partition, since Linux uses different filesystems than Windows. The Ubuntu Installer will make the right kind of Partition by default.

Good luck installing Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. Windows can even do the job:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Can-I-repartition-my-hard-disk

You might have a problem with your c-drive though. It wont shrink while you have your page file on there, so you will have to disable that temporarily while shrinking.

Comment: As Ewald said, you don't have to make a new partition in windows, and if you do, the partition will be gone once you install Ubuntu. Windows wont recognize it as a partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can resize that partition using Windows disk manager or by running GParted from Live Ubuntu CD. 
For Gparted look here
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/

and for using Windows Vista disk manager follow instructions here
http://www.mydigitallife.info/change-or-resize-partition-ntfs-fat-or-fat32-size-in-windows-vista/