# Installing ubuntu 12.04 on a separate partition

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have a 320GB hp-mini netbook, which originally had 2 partitions (C: ~300GB, and D:(recovery) ~20GB). I shrank the C: drive, and created a 50GB unallocated partition, which i want to use for my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, but on loading  Ubuntu via USB, I'm stuck as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: This post is helpful http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/10/12/ubuntu-10-10-manual-disk-partitioning-guide/

Answer (score 3):

- Boot with live usb
- There will be screen asking for install options like `install along with windows 7`,`install ubuntu as only OS` etc. Choose **Do something else** option at the end.
- Now partition tool will open. You can see the unallocated space. Select that and then click on `Add`.
- Now we will add `SWAP` partition. Give disk space value as `1024MB` (1GB) or 2GB. If you have good amount of RAM (~2GB), 1GB swap space is enough. Select `SWAP` in file system dropdown.Press "OK".
- Now again continue previous step for the rest free space. This time select filesytem as `ext4` and mount point as `/`.
- Check in partition tool window, grub installation location is same as your hard disk not your usb disk. (most likely `bootloader location -> in sda ...`)
- Now go ahead and installation will finish in minutes.

Note: Don't enable downloading of 3rd party apps and update in previous screen. Better don't connect to internet while installing.Good luck. Let us know how it went.

Comment: Just a little correction: The partitioning tool in Ubiquity is _not_ gparted.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64671/how-to-partition-a-disk-for-installing-ubuntu).You don't need to install any software but Ubuntu can do everything itself.Fully Read this post & answer and proceed.