# Help with Partition for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to partition a disk for installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64671/how-to-partition-a-disk-for-installing-ubuntu)

I have an Alienware M14x with 8 GB RAM. I am thinking of installing UBUNTU 12.04 LST using about 30 GB space on my hard drive. I am not use about how much of each partition I should do (/, /home, /boot, swap, etc). 
I am going to share a drive from Windows 7 which is about 550 GB (Has games, documents, programming documents (Java, Python, etc), Music & Downloads (Torrents & Download manager)). 
If 30GB seems too low/high, then don't hesitate to throw your suggestions. I'd only use Ubuntu for programming & some media use (movies, music)

Please I need suggestions asap!

Any help should be appreciated! Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Swap if you want to use hibernation features should be the same as the amount of ram you have.

People usually recommend making your /home directory a separate partition and your boot partition (like 200mb or 300 if you want extra kernels) can safely be smaller as long as you delete old kernels when upgrading.

30 GBs should be fine and you can always increase/decrease partition sizes at a later date if need be.

You should still be able to download media files to your windows partition that way you can still access it if you need to use windows and keeping you from having to make partition changes until you finally decide to use Ubuntu full time :D