# Unable to install Ubuntu on Asus EeePC1011CX: BIOS not listing bootable USBs

Tags: asus, bios, lts

I had been trying to install Ubuntu 12.4LTS on my netbook Eee PC 1011CX with preloaded Windows7.

1. I successfully created a bootable USB stick (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) following pendrivelinux.com
2. Then with Esc key at powering up, I could pick the bootable USB and load Ubuntu successfully. Ubuntu loads, so far so good. Now I decide to install it "within win7" dual boot. 
   Now here is the issue:
3. With Esc key, I could see that there are three devices listed to pick: (1) The main SAT drive, (2) Generic USB 0.0, (3) UEFI generic USB 0.0 -- out of these three, options (1) and (3) load Win7, and (2) is what loads Ubuntu.
4. But when I get into BIOS using F2 key to change the boot order, I see only device options (1) and (3) listed there. Option (2) "Generic USB 0.0" is missing.
5. So: the system cannot reboot into Ubuntu during installation process and the process is terminated every time the system restarts. Installation doesn't proceed even if I manually pick to install using Esc key. 
   Is there anyway to ask BIOS to show the generic USB option? I have tested the USB on another machine, and also I have tried doing the same procedure using an ext.HDD only to see the same trend.

Please advice. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact option you are choosing `Install ubuntu alongside Windows` or `Within Windows`? Because within windows means wubi installation. If you are booting via usb it should not be wubi install.

For Dual boot:

No nothing can be done from ubuntu side to make BIOS understand the USB. Possibly a firmware bug in vendors firmware. See if there are any BIOS update available.

If updating BIOS / No update is there for BIOS. I would recommend to manually resize windows 7 disk and create partition for ubuntu and install ubuntu into it. In this method you don't need to reboot until installation is finished.

[Here is a guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/65416/35775). There are many in internet and this site.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your bootable pendrive

Go to your bios by presssing F2

Go to last option tab in BIOS where you will find list of bootable pendrive
 ( I dont know tab name(other than boot option) but one of the tab will list the bootable device attached)