# New Ubuntu install onto new hard drive that I also want to use for Win 7 backups

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, format

So I have a brand new 1TB hard drive I want to partition off to install Ubuntu, but I want to use the majority of the space on it as my backup drive for Windows 7.  I've got it wired up and ready to be formatted in Windows 7, but I'm not sure exactly how I should proceed or even if this is a good idea to begin with.  Thoughts?

Comment: For formatting it is recommended you use the partitioner on Ubuntu's live media (USB or DVD). In particular, Windows does not "understand" Linux filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** Create an NTFS partition of the size you want for Windows backup. Leave the rest of the drive unformatted for Ubuntu installation.

**Step 2** Choose ”Something Else" during Ubuntu installation. See [How do I partition a drive so that the data is separate from the operating system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227203/disk-partition-ubuntu-12-10) for details partitions for Ubuntu.

**Step 3** See [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) for the rest of two drive setup.