# I want to install Ubuntu 13 on the last drive, along side Windows 7 via USB stick

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I know exactly how to install Ubuntu by Wubi alongside Windows 7, but actually as have free space and want to install it on the last drive, how can I tell Ubuntu to be installed on drive "i", means what I'm seeing is `sda lyk` stuff...

All I want to know is how can I install

1. on last drive "i"
2. along with working Windows 7
3. without deleting or formatting other drive, as I have important and useful data there at present.

drive "i" is free and has 17GiB [image: My drives]

Comment: During the installation wizard to select which partition to install Ubuntu, you will be presented with options. Find the option to install ubuntu alongside windows

Please also check http://askubuntu.com/questions/64671/how-to-partition-a-disk-for-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself ,it was not a problem  actually ,  jus not understanding SDA drives and all . So mentioning here to what I did to make it simple-

1. In windows I deleted the last drive in which I supposed to install ubuntu 13.04.
2. Then changes the `Boot Priorities` to `USB`and reboot.
3. Then started installation normally till it asks for `Where to install` like shown below -

[image: Image taken from softpedia.]

4.Then after clicking the option `Something Else` , it was showing all my partitions along with `Free Space`

5.I used `Free Space` where I wanted to install it without afecting others and Entered the values for making `SWAP Area` as 4gigs as I am having 4gigs of ram ,and rest all for root directory`(/)` where everything is about to be installed.

6.After everything completes , I got what I want as shown below-

[image: Here]

7.Remember in my question I was asking to do so with 17 gigs of partition , and in the picture its 47gigs , because i have changes the partition size for that, Its better now.